# What is the fastest method to populate a QListView from the content of a QFile?

Tags: c#, c++, qt, qlistview, qfile

Using **QFile**, I am reading a plain text file that contains 16,280 vocabularies, each in a new line. Then I am appending the content line by line to a **QStringList**. The **QStringList** is fed into a **QStringListModel** that populates a **QListView**.

Appending the **QFile** content line by line to a **QStringList** is killing me having to wait for a long time. Here is my code:

```js
void MainWindow::populateListView()
{
    QElapsedTimer elapsedTimer;
    elapsedTimer.start();

    // Create model
    stringListModel = new QStringListModel(this);

    // open the file
    QFile file("Data\\zWordIndex.txt");
    if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) {
         statusBar()->showMessage("Cannot open file: " + file.fileName());
    }    

    // teststream to read from file
    QTextStream textStream(&file);

    while (true)
    {
        QString line = textStream.readLine();
        if (line.isNull())
            break;
        else
            stringList.append(line); // populate the stringlist
    }

    // Populate the model
    stringListModel->setStringList(stringList);

    // Glue model and view together
    ui->listView->setModel(stringListModel);

    //Select the first listView index and populateTextBrowser
    const QModelIndex &index = stringListModel->index(0,0);
    ui->listView->selectionModel()->select(index, QItemSelectionModel::Select);
    populateTextBrowser(index);

    //Show time
    statusBar()->showMessage("Loaded in " + QString::number(elapsedTimer.elapsed()) + " milliseconds");
}
```

I also developed the same app in C#. In C# I simply use: `listBox1.DataSource = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);` which is so much so fast, lightning fast.

This time I am developing my app in **C++** with **Qt**. Could you please kindly tell me a similar method, the fastest method, to populate a **QListView** from the content of a **QFile**?

Comment: Which part of the above code snippet is taking the longest?

Comment: This part of the code is taking the longest time: `while (true)
    {
        QString line = textStream.readLine();
        if (line.isNull())
            break;
        else
            stringList.append(line);
    }`

Comment: well if the reading the file is taking longer then anything else then you have to optimize this part. How about to read the whole thing with read(char * data, qint64 maxSize ) and parse it afterwards?

Comment: I can read the whole file at once by `file.readAll()`. But then how to `parse` it in a flash? Could you please kindly give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `QTextSteam` here does not give you any benefit, it only has some overhead. Using `QFile` directly is probably much faster :

```
while (!file.atEnd())
{
   QByteArray lineData = file.readLine();
   QString line(lineData);
   stringList.append(line.trimmed()); // populate the stringlist
}
```

An other way is read the total file using `readAll` and parse it using `split` :

```
stringList = QString(file.readAll()).split("\n", QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

Comment: The while condition `while (file.canReadLine())` is not working. It does not read anything. But the while condition `while (!file.atEnd())` works. And also the `QByteArray lineData = file.readLine();
   QString line(lineData);
   stringList.append(line);` produces an extra padding at the bottom of each line of the `stringList`. However, the `QTextSteam` method does not produce that.

Comment: Thank you so much. The code `stringList = QString(file.readAll()).split("\n", QString::SkipEmptyParts);` is really so fast, faster than the `while` loop method. I am so happy now. Thank you so much again. :)

Comment: So which of the two methods is the fastest?

Comment: @user2672165 It seems that the second method is faster.

Comment: The second method is the faster C++ method. However, as I compared with it's C# equivalent method `listBox1.DataSource = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);`, the second method is still 3-4 milliseconds slower compared to the C#'s. I wanted a C++ app because I thought that C++ is the fastest of all programming languages. But I don;t know why in this case C# is the fastest.